# solving second order ODE with $\operatorname{sech}^2(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the equation of the following type:
$$u''(x) = (a-b\operatorname{sech}^2(cx))u(x),$$
where $a,b,c$ are positive real constants.

It is my first time when I met the equation which includes $\operatorname{sech}^2(x)u$ function.

Any hint will be good for me! Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Moo yeah, i saw that, but I need to solve it anyway :/

Comment: @Moo no, i need exact form of the solution. I am not sure if it solvable, but this article https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4725/6fa58ee1fd9ef8b9eb71814ef46dc5a12d56.pdf (Example 3.1.1) says that the particular case can be solved by hypergeometric series.

Comment: It is a pitty that $c\neq 1$. In such a case, there is an explicit solution in terms of associated Legendre polynomials.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici this equation I got from the spectral problem for the operator $L_+$ of the NLS equation with nonlinearity of type $|u|^{2p}u$. The number $c$ in the equation is defined by $c=p$, so it is possible that $c \neq 1$ :/

Answer (score 0):

There is a class of solution possible provided you allow for a relation between coefficients a and b. Try the solution $(\operatorname{sech}(cx))^p$ and find two algebraic equations detailing the dependence of the power $p$ on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Hello and  welcome to MSE! To make stuff readable for us here, we use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make life easier to both who asked the question and to anyone else who will read this answer. Click on the link to learn how to typeset your answers textbook style and your contributions will be well-received here